# sending mail using XAMPP, sendmail, and gmail smtp server

Tags: php, smtp, xampp, sendmail.exe

This seems like something fairly straightforward and my php script is able to execute. However I am never receiving the mail.  Here is the relevant code:

**php.ini**

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/smtp
;SMTP = localhost
; http://php.net/smtp-port
;smtp_port = 25

sendmail_path = "C:\xampplite\sendmail\sendmail.exe -t -i"
```

**sendmail.ini**

```
smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com

smtp_port=587
smtp_ssl=auto
default_domain=mydomain.com
error_logfile=error.log
debug_logfile=debug.log
auth_username=username50@gmail.com
auth_password=passpass

force_sender=myemail@gmail.com
hostname=smtp.gmail.com
```

Is there anything here I'm missing? My script is sending email to myself. That wouldn't be a problem right?

```
<?php
$to = "blah@gmail.com";
$subject = "Test mail";
$message = "Hello! This is a simple email message.";
$from = "someonelse@example.com";
$headers = "From:" . $from;
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
echo "Mail Sent.";
?>
```

Comment: did you fire up mercury?

Comment: i didnt turn on mercury.  i was under the impression its not necessary if you are using an external smtp server the way im using gmail

Comment: Have you got the right port? Port for SSL: 465

Comment: i tried changing it to 465 with no luck

Comment: smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=465
smtp_ssl=auto

default_domain=gmail.com
auth_username=user50@gmail.com
auth_password=pass
force_sender=myemail@gmail.com
hostname=gmail.com

this works

Comment: What does it means "this works"? Have you solved the whole problem (can receive e-mails) or just was able to set port 465 as adviced? In first case, put a formal answer to your own question, so others can see it and make use of it.

Comment: Use PHPMailer package!

Answer (score -1):

Try this

**sendmail.ini**

**[sendmail]**

```
smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=465
smtp_ssl=ssl
error_logfile=error.log
debug_logfile=debug.log
auth_username=[email]@gmail.com
auth_password=[email password]
pop3_server=
pop3_username=
pop3_password=
force_sender=[email]@gmail.com
force_recipient=
hostname=smtp.gmail.com
```

**php.ini**

**[mail function]**

```
SMTP = smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port = 465
sendmail_path = "\"C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"
mail.add_x_header=Off
```